# Configure ElasticSearch to use ngram by default. - SQL LIKE %% behavior

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Is it possible to configure the elasticsearch index behavior to ack as the LIKE keyword of SQL.

If the index contains "This document is called MySuperInvoice", I want to be able to find it if I am looking for super, doc or voice"

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

Somebody tells me that I need to put * around my search terms : `*query*`

Lets see how this can be done using haystack.

Comment: Could you add a question? What is your issue?

Comment: Yes the question is how should I do? I tried with this configuration but it doesn't seams to work. Do you have any idea of how I should configure ElasticSearch so it act like I want?

Comment: Perhaps can you post here your curl commands to help us to reproduce your issue. I mean: a document, a search request at least.

Comment: I am using haystack as an elasticsearch backend so i don't write my own json curl requests. But I would like to configure directly this behaviour for all requests in the ``/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`` file

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791075/in-elasticsearch-how-do-i-search-for-an-arbitrary-substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got there. Thanks @zebuline.

```
cluster:
        name: webapp
network:
        bind_host: 0.0.0.0
        publish_host: _eth0_
index:
        analysis:
                analyzer:
                        default_index:
                                type:           custom
                                tokenizer:      standard
                                filter:         [standard, lowercase, asciifolding, webapp_ngram]
                        default_search:
                                type:           custom
                                tokenizer:      standard
                                filter:         [standard, lowercase, asciifolding]
                filter:
                        webapp_ngram:
                                type:           nGram
                                min_gram:       1
                                max_gram:       30
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at default mapping in ES. It should help you.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: It doesn't seams to help me :s