# How to setup ElasticSearch to do SQL LIKE "%" for email addresses?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, tire

In SQL, I can search email addresses pretty well with SQL LIKE.

With an email "stack@domain.com", searching "stack", "@domain.com", "domain.com", or "domain" would get me back the desired email address.

How can I get the same result with ElasticSearch?

I played with nGram, edgeNGram, uax_url_email, etc and the search results have been pretty bad. Please correct me if I'm wrong, it sounds like I have to do the following:

1. for index_analyzer

   - use "keyword", "whitespace", or "uax_url_email" tokenizer so the email don't get tokenized

     - but wildcard queries don't seem to work (with tire at least)
   - use "nGram" or "edgeNGram" for filter

     - I always get way too many unwanted results like getting "first@domain.com" when searching "first-second".
2. for search_analyzer

   - don't do nGram

One experiment code

```
tire.settings :number_of_shards => 1,
            :number_of_replicas => 1,
            :analysis => {
                :filter => {
                    :db_ngram  => {
                        "type"     => "nGram",
                        "max_gram" => 255,
                        "min_gram" => 3 }
                },
                :analyzer => {
                    :string_analyzer => {
                        "tokenizer"    => "standard",
                        "filter"       => ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "db_ngram"],
                        "type"         => "custom" },
                    :index_name_analyzer => {
                        "tokenizer"    => "standard",
                        "filter"       => ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                        "type"         => "custom" },
                    :search_name_analyzer => {
                        "tokenizer"    => "whitespace",
                        "filter"       => ["lowercase", "db_ngram"],
                        "type"         => "custom" },
                    :index_email_analyzer => {
                        "tokenizer"    => "whitespace",
                        "filter"       => ["lowercase"],
                        "type"         => "custom" }
                }
            } do
    mapping do
      indexes :id,           :index    => :not_analyzed
      indexes :name,         :index_analyzer => 'index_name_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'search_name_analyzer'
      indexes :email,        :index_analyzer => 'index_email_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'search_email_analyzer'
    end
end
```

Specific cases that don't work well:

- emails with hyphen (eg. email-hyphen@domain.com)
- query string '@' at the beginning or end
- exact matches
- searching with wildcard like '*@*' gets very unexpected results.

Suppose I have, "aaa@email.com", "aaa_0@email.com", and "aaa-0@email.com, searching "aaa" gives me "aaa@a.com" "aaa-0@email.com. Searching "aaa*" give me everything, but "aaa-*" gives me nothing. So, how should I do **exact match wildcard** queries? For these type of queries, I get pretty much the same results for different tokenizer/analyzer.

I do these after each mapping change:
    Model.tire.index.delete
    Model.tire.create_elasticsearch_index
    Model.tire.index.import Model.all

References:

- [Configure ElasticSearch to use ngram by default. - SQL LIKE %% behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160295/configure-elasticsearch-to-use-ngram-by-default-sql-like-behavior)
- http://euphonious-intuition.com/2012/08/more-complicated-mapping-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791075/in-elasticsearch-how-do-i-search-for-an-arbitrary-substring

Answer (score 0):

Considering what you are trying to accomplish, `KeywordAnalyzer` might be a reasonable choice of analyzer, though I don't see anything that would cause problems with a `WhitespaceAnalyzer`.

I suspect you are running into problems with the query parsing and analysis, although you haven't really described how you are querying.  Simplest case would be to simply use [term](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query/) or [prefix](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/prefix-query/) queries.

It does seem a bit like `StandardAnalyzer` would serve your purpose here, mostly (differentiating between "aaa_0" and "aaa-0" would be a problem), as long as it is applied consistently, and your query is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the query is straightforward, only one string/term.

    Model.tire.search(:load => true, :per_page => 25) do
        query { string "*com" }
    end

I tried prefix, I suppose "@.gmail.com" won't work. I could not figure out how to do wildcard queries with the tire gem yet, otherwise I would chain exact query with wildcard queries to search emails different way.

    boolean :minimum_number_should_match => 1 do
          should { prefix 'email', term }
          should { prefix 'email.exact', term }
          should { string term }
        end